# factor group $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{175} /\mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Suppose I have a factor group $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{175} /\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. What is it?
$$\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{175}=\mathbb{Z}^*_{25}\times \mathbb{Z}^*_{7}=\mathbb{Z}_{20}\times \mathbb{Z}_{6}.$$
$(\mathbb{Z}_{20}\times \mathbb{Z}_{6})/\mathbb{Z}_2=\mathbb{Z}_{10}\times \mathbb{Z}_{6}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{20}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: As you see the notation $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{175} /\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ doesn't make sense. Maybe you meant $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{175} / \pm 1$.

Comment: There are a few subgroups of $\Bbb $Z_{175}^*$ that are isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$, and the quotients are not all the same.